# Blur Not matching the size of the image view Swift

Tags: swift, image, view, uiblureffect

[image]

I'm trying to create a blurry login screen and I looked up how to do it online.  When I apply the constraints to the image view, (from what I understand/think) it doesnt apply to the blurred out part.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var mainBackgroundImage: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.blurMainImg()
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func blurMainImg(){
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurView.frame = mainBackgroundImage.bounds
        mainBackgroundImage.addSubview(blurView)
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: What about mainBackgroundImage constraints? Can you post in your question some picture?

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano I added a picture of the storyboard and the constraints for the image

Comment: Excellent work man, now your question is more clear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have post in your picture seems it's a matter of constraints (leading and trailing) you must delete it and put trailing constraint to Superview = 0, the same for leading -> Superview = 0

An example (look for trailing and leading):

[image]

P.S.: dont forgot to silent warning by update your constraints (tap the yellow triangle and flag for all)

[image]

Comment: http://imgur.com/FtRevbd  I think something went wrong.  The image isnt the full size of the screen and the blur part is still not the same size.

Comment: You must silent warnings (the yellow triangle when you set constraints) by clicking on it and update constraints (all)

Comment: When I change the trailing and leading to 0 it just shrinks the main image it doesnt change anything with the blur.  i currently have 0 warnings but it still doesnt work